How to establish authenticate, authorize from AKS deployed Container to Azure Event Hub
Apologies if my question is trivial. I have limited knowledge with Azure security.
( Identity , principal id, entra id....)
In my container app model, identity was created and used in Event Hub role assignments. This is good.
Scenario:
I have a AKS cluster
Image in ACR registry
created deployment - kubectl create deployment <> --image=my.azureacr.io/imagename:v3
deployment.apps/somename created
I can understand why - kubectl get deployment is giving available 0.
(workloads show amber triangle)
I dont know how to check logs
application properties
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.namespace=hents
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.processor.checkpoint-store.account-name=mynd
spring.cloud.azure.eventhubs.processor.checkpoint-store.container-name=temckpoint

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.supply-out-0.destination=sb

spring.cloud.function.definition=supply;
spring.cloud.stream.poller.initial-delay=0
spring.cloud.stream.poller.fixed-delay=1000

There is no connection string or shared access signature.  example -microsoft
Questions:
How to enable authentication/authorization/trust between AKS app and eventhub ?
Thanks

is it related to container app or aks ?

az aks update --resource-group stc-rg --name akub --enable-managed-identity
this seems to work
